# How to do this matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

Assume I have this array

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2\end{bmatrix}$$

and I have another array as

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}3&3&3\end{bmatrix}$$

I want the output to be

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}6&6&6\end{bmatrix}$$

It can't be $C=AB$ as they don't have the correct dimensions. It can't be $\ A^T$ or $\ B^T$ as that will give me a scalar.

How on earth do I do this?

Comment: Termwise multiply? $(a_1,a_2,a_3).(b_1,b_2,b_3)=(a_1.b_1,a_2.b_2,a_3.b_3)$

Comment: I assume you want something that you can implement in a (matlab?) programm or not?

Comment: The [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29)?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).